# EF Core creating unexpected 1:1 relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have an Accounts table, holding bank accounts. When a user selects an account, the budget to which that account might use, is defaulted. So in the Account table, I have a `DefaultBudget` column.

Additionally, A budget, in my case, is linked to an account. That is, when predicting future balances, the user assignes a budget to an account.

There are two separate links. You need to have an account before you can create a budget for it (Create budget, assign Account - required). But you can then go modify account, and assign a default budget - not required).

So, my code first account:

```
internal class Account : EntityAudit
{
    [Key, Required, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required, Column(Order = 1)]
    public Guid ExternalId { get; set; }

    [Required, Column(Order = 2)]
    public AccountTypes AccountTypeId { get; set; }

    public decimal? OpeningBalance { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime? DateOpened { get; set; }

    [Required, Column(Order = 3)]
    public UserAccount UserAccount { get; set; }

    [Required, Column(Order = 4)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool IsFavourite { get; set; }

    public Subcategory DefaultSubCategory { get; set; }

    public Budget DefaultBudget { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
```

}

The key field here being `public Budget DefaultBudget { get; set; }`. So, not required, and I'd expected a FK to be created to the Budget table.

And my Budget code first object:

```
 internal class Budget : EntityAudit
    {
        [Required, Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required, Column(Order = 1)]
        public Guid ExternalId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public BudgetType BudgetType { get; set; }

        [Required, Column(Order = 2)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required, ForeignKey("PrimaryAccountId")]
        public Account PrimaryAccount { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

        public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

        [Required, Column(Order = 3)]
        public UserAccount UserAccount { get; set; }

        [Required, Column(Order = 4)]
        public decimal AllowanceAmount { get; set; }

        public virtual List<TransactionLine> TransactionLines { get; set; }
    }
```

In this object, I have `public Account PrimaryAccount { get; set; }`. Note, required, and I tried to specify the FK name.

However, when I generate my migrations, the table structure I end up with is:

[image]

It's created a 1:1 relationship between the two tables. I'm not sure why this is happening and how to get around it.

A budget can be linked to many accounts, and many accounts can be linked to a budget. That sounds like a many to many - but even thatisn't quite right. It should have created a `DefaultBudgetId` in the accounts table.

Comment: `So in the Account table, I have a DefaultBudget column` - i'd have a think about that - dosn't seem right...

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty confusing. A user can specify which Budget a transaction will be assigned to. Now, that is based on the account that is selected. For example, I say that I am paying money to KFC. KFC is an account in my system, of type ThirdParty". So when that account is selected, the 'selected budget' on screen, defaults to the one assigned to KFC. It's not required - the user can change it. It's just a way of making data entry quick. Therefore, the account has a 'DefaultBudget' column, which points to a Budget.

Comment: So that's for the relationship "An account might have a Budget". The other key is that, when I create a budget, the user must select an Account, which this budget might effect. So, I have a weekly spending budget. That budget is liked to my 'Everyday Account'. That allows me to predict future balances for account, taking into concideration that budgets are being allocated weekly to each account, so when forecasting an account, I need to ensure I reduce the balance based on any budgets. So a separate relationship. It's between Account and Budget, but serve different purposes.

Comment: i'd recommend not building that into the model, but in rules or default value behaviour in the code

Comment: I was thinking of adding an 'AccountDefaults', which an AccountId, a BudgetId and a SubcategoryId. And rather use that. That gets rid of the strange 1:1 mapping. Now it would be 1:0 account to account defaults...

Comment: "A budget can be linked to many accounts, and many accounts can be linked to a budget. That sounds like a many to many."  Not quite.  A budget can be linked to many accounts and an account can be linked to many budgets.  Now it sounds like many to many.